# Why is using Federated Identities to Sign into application managed by Cognito trying to update email and password

Tags: amazon-cognito

I have configured a UserPool that has phonenumber and email as required attributes.  When I add a federated identity provider that utilizes SAML to authenticate I am able to create a cognito pool user when I first sign in via through my federated identity provider.  However, subsequent sign in attempts fail. and my idpResponse claim that the email and phonenumber attribute can not be updated.  My idp has not updated these values so unsure what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this was happening was because the required attribute was marked as immutable.  THe documentation on AWS is a little misleading since it seems to suggest that only custom attributes need to be mutable.  General attributes also need to be mutable, but this is set to mutable by default.  Any manual edits done by the consumer will override this default behavior.